# C# LinearGradientBrush Bitmap repeating Vertically

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, bitmap, gradient

I am playing around with the Microsoft Vision API and learning C# as I go, and one of the properties of a Vision object is an "Accent Color" of the image.

From a series of images analysed, I want to show those colors ordered in a Linear Gradient -- because that will be able to show the user that most pictures are (for example) blue, because Blue colors take up half of the gradient etc.

I have this working, in that I am ordering the Colors by Hue, and able to produce a Linear Gradient I am filling into a Bitmap.

BUT, the gradient by default is Horizontal, and I need Vertical -- so I've used **LinearGradientBrush.RotateTransform(90)** which rotates that actual gradient fine, but doesn't seem to fill the entire Rectangle, and it repeats. This is what I'm getting as a result:

[image]

**How do I create a Vertical LinearGradient that fills up the entire Height of the Rectangle object for my Bitmap?**

Here is my code:

```
    private Bitmap CreateColorGradient(System.Drawing.Rectangle rect, System.Drawing.Color[] colors)
    {
        Bitmap gradient = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

        LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, System.Drawing.Color.White, System.Drawing.Color.White, 0, false);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();

        // Positions
        List<float> positions = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++) positions.Add((float)i / (colors.Length - 1));
        cb.Positions = positions.ToArray();

        cb.Colors = colors;
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;
        br.RotateTransform(90);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(gradient))
            g.FillRectangle(br, rect);

        return gradient;
    }
```

Thanks for reading and any help -- also if you see something in my code that could be done better please point it out it helps me learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the `angle` parameter in the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s29t28a2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And as you instead do a rotation on the Grahics object your brush rectangle is no longer correctly fits the target bitmap and the gradient can't fill it; so it repeats.

To correct

- simply set the angle to `90` and
- remove the `br.RotateTransform(90);` call.

Here this changes the result from the left to the middle version:

[image][image][image]

While we're looking at it, do take note of the `WrapMode` property of `LinearGradientBrush`. What you see in the first image is the default `WrapMode.Clamp`. Often a changing to one of the Flip mode helps.. So lets have a look at the impact of it one the first version at the right position.

It looks like  `WrapMode.TileFlipY` but since I have brought back the rotation it actually takes a  value `WrapMode.TileFlipX` or  `WrapMode.TileFlipXY`: 
`br.WrapMode = WrapMode.TileFlipX;`

Comment: No problem. Do have a look at the last remarks about the WrapMode, which often comes handy..